# Is there a Debian based distro that I can build myself?

Tags: linux, debian, desktop-environment

I simply want a Debian based system where *I* can install the DE and other stuff. Arch is OK but there are some weird errors. Please gimme your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

As far I'm really aware of, there aren't many minimal GNU/Linux distributions like Arch, or any that are based on Debian. The best option in my mind would be to follow the [Linux From Scratch](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org) Project for building and [Debian Source Packages](https://wiki.debian.org/Packaging/SourcePackage) for finding their packages.